# How to sort a map by a specific field in js (react)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I sort this by name?

Can anybody help me with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort the array beforehand with `Array#sort` e.g.

```
underlyings.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
```